# Empathy crashes when I open the acount manager

Tags: empathy

Empathy is working with my google and facebook accounts, but every time I attempt to open the account manager it presents the account manager windows briefly and then closes it.
The application continues to work after that, but I cannot edit my account settings or add a new account to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same bug. I have also an google account and a facebook one. Empathy working fine but the account manager is automaticaly close when I open it.
I tried to reinstall it with "sudo apt-get install --reinstall empathy" but it doesn't solve the problem.

My conf is Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0-55-generic-pae, the system is up to date.

==

I solved the problem :

1. close Empathy
2. delete your config
   rm -rf .config/Empathy/
3. delete your keys (stored in gnome keyring)
4. restart Empathy